# permission to READ_CALL_LOG is not working in react-native expo

Tags: react-native, permissions, expo, calllog

**why can't get the permission to READ_CALL_LOG in react-native expo with this code?
is possible to access call log in expo?**

```
const CallLogFunc = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_CALL_LOG,
      {
        title: " Permission neeeded",
        message: "Allow App to access your phone call logs",
        buttonNeutral: "Ask Me Later",
        buttonNegative: "Cancel",
        buttonPositive: "OK",
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log("CALL LOG permission granted");
    } else {
      console.log("CALL LOG permission denied");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you defined the permission in app.json for android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expo does not support READ_CALL_LOG permission. Please refer this issue in [expo github](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1096).

Answer (score 2):

Check if `READ_CALL_LOG` permission is there in your `app.json`, if no then add it like below

```
{
  "expo": {
    ....
    ....
    "android":{
      "permissions":["READ_CALL_LOG"],
      "package":"your package name here"
    }
  }
}
```

Ref : [Permissions](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/app/#permissions)